# Postgres foreign key to multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have the following conceptual problem for whom I haven't been able to come up with a satisfying solution yet.
I'll explain it with an example.

I have 2 tables, `cats` and `dogs`, which are made up of different attributes (they need to be different tables as my real case is actually more complex).
I can feed these 'animals' and I want to keep track of some info about this feeding operation (say `[animal_fed]`, `food_type`, `food_quantity`, `date`, ...).

By now I am using a `feeds` table with the following schema: `animal_id INTEGER`, `table_name VARCHAR(50)` (could be `"cats"` or `"dogs"`, but there gonna be lots of more species..), `[other fields]`.

I'am completely unsatisfied with this solution cause it makes it a pain (if even possible, but a way there must be..) to `select from feeds` retrieving also some info on the animal been fed (similarly to `join`).

How can I better approach this problem?

Would using a 'parent' table represent a good solution?

Or if you think my actual approach is good how can I make a `"join"` to get, say, all the `feeds` info plus the animal `name`?

Thank you.

Comment: No you cannot have one FK pointing to eiter the cats or the dogs tables. The standard trick is to put all the animals in the same table, and add a field to describe the animal-species.

Comment: @joop the thing is mine is a simplified example. The actual entities have quite a different nature from each other, so I am not able to put them all in the same table. A better example would be `planes` and `pens` which can undergo `maintenance` and I need to keep track of `maintenance.date`. I know I can't create 'proper' `fk` to multiple tables but I need a workaround. Tnx by the way!

Comment: It was a simplified answer, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to improve it, but your solution is nearly good:

1. **Put all animals in one table**. You said they need to be different, but maybe you can merge them. Final `animals` table will have all columns from both table. And you will have column `animal_type` which will be either *dog* or *cat*.
2. **Multiple SQL queries**. You leave everything as it is and make some method/function to get data you need. Make a query to get *all feeds* and then in another query you can get those animals. If you want to limit the query you can add condition `FROM animals WHERE id IN ( ANIMAL_ID_FROM_PREVIOUS_RESULT )`. Then you have to merge these in your application.
3. **You can make two relation tables.** You will have the `animals` table ane the `feeds` table and you create `r_dog_feed` and `r_cat_feed`. They will have `feed_id` which will refer to `feeds` table and then either `dog_id` or `cat_id`. Then you can write SQL using [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp):

SELECT dogs.name as name, food.* FROM r_dog_feed
JOIN dogs ON dogs.id = r_dog_feed.dog_id
JOIN feeds ON feeds.id = r_dog_feed.feed_id
UNION
SELECT cats.name as name, food.* FROM r_cat_feed
JOIN catsON dogs.id = r_cat_feed.cat_id
JOIN feeds ON feeds.id = r_cat_feed.feed_id

Comment: tnx for your reply. Method 2 seems the most viable at the moment as:
- method 1: as I answered to @joop the entities have very different nature and this approach would lead to creating a table with more than 70% of empty fields
- method 3: animals->feeds is more a `1 to N` relationship and this approach would lead to an `N to N` relationship (but I could for sure try this approach also)

Comment: The second one is called **polymorphic relationship** and it's basically what you started: you have columns `_id` and `_type` and by the `_type` you tell which table it referes to. Here is a better exapmle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918811/database-best-practices with **UNION**. I think it will do what you need.

Comment: This is a good one. At least now I am able to retrieve al the data I need. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot put the data of cats and dogs in the same table, then another good solution is to have an animals table that holds the common data of cats and dogs. You can then setup a one-to-zero-or-one relation between between animals and cats, and between animals and dogs.

On animals you add an animal_type that tells you on which other table you will find the specific extra info.

On cats and dogs you add an animal_id with FK to the animals table.

On feeds you have the animal_id and FK to the animals table.

**Pros**

You can easily handle a relation between feeds and animals. SQL than only needs to access common animal info is easy to write.

Some application frameworks do support "inherited" data subtypes and do handle most of this for you. But since you say nothing about what you are using for your application, I'm not sure this applies.

**Cons**

You cannot enforce integrity with database constraint only. You will need triggers or application logic to guarantee no cat or dog refer to the same animal_id, and that each animal is either a cat or a dog (if this is one of your requirements).

When you need to access cat and dog extra info, you will probably need separate SQL statements, as the structure is different and the access to the data must use different tables.

If you need to add other animal types, you will be adding tables... and also adding different SQL to access the extra info... this is not pretty, and may get out of hand.

Comment: Tnx. This also is a useful answer. Actually the fact of not being able to enforce integrity with db constraints is a bit of an issue. I was thinking myself (as you can see from my question) of using a kinda parent table for my entities. By the way this could be the approach I'll be moving to in the medium run.